# SSL Certificate use on instances created from AMI and validity

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-ami

After setting up an EC2 instance, and installing an SSL Certificate for a specific domain,  I plan to create an image of the instance (AMI).  Then I will terminate the original instance, and launch a new instance from the AMI, replacing the 1st instance, the new instance now having the same domain.

My question is whether the SSL Certificate would continue to be valid on the new instance that replaced the 1st one. And, what specifically is needed to implement other than the usual certificate configuration, if any.  Use case for this arrangement is having the ability to terminate and launch new instances, both for spot requests, and having a secure web server launched as needed from an image.

I researched and couldn't find any reference.

The instance in this case is a Windows Web server, not that it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes; after setting up and configuring SSL on Windows IIS Server, it's possible to create an image (AMI), and launch it later, assigning the original domain name, and it will continue to work.